# What does $mech->xpath() return using WWW::Mechanize::Firefox?

Tags: perl, xpath, www-mechanize-firefox

What does `$mech->xpath()` return using `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`?

The [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~corion/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.79/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox.pm#$mech-%3Expath(_$query,_%25options_)) says it `"Returns the matched results."`, which doesn't help.

What object or array of objects is returned and where is a specification of this object so I can reference its member variables and methods?

So far I have guessed that this is relevant: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element

Comment: The method returns the node(s) of the XML (the HTML-Document you run it against) which match your selector.
Have you tried to use the Data::Dumper to look into your result? (e.g. print Dumper($mech->xpath( [yourXpathQuery] ) )

Answer (score 0):

It returns a `MozRepl::RemoteObject::Instance` object.